# Rest API query for Django and js

Tags: javascript, python, django

For example I am making a Instagram clone , if a user send me message how will I get it , I mean do I have to run a while True loop and make infinite fetch calls in it or is there any other way of getting stuff done ;btw using a REST_API in python And Django

Comment: Puling, pushing or can use sockets

Comment: Thanks i will user djagno sockets